# Alternative for g_array_append_val in C

Tags: c, compression

I am writing a program to implement the LZ77 compression algorithm. I am using [this program](https://github.com/dbrgn/algorithms/blob/master/lz/lz77.c)
as my reference, I am trying to switch the functions from the "glib" library to more standard functions of C. And now I have trouble replacing "g_array_append_val" as the conversions it seems this function is doing are incompatible. Any help would be appreciated, here is my current program:

```
typedef struct {
short start;
short length;
char first_mismatch;
} reference;
char *lookahead = NULL;
reference matchref = {0, 0, *lookahead};
GArray *symbols = g_array_new(false, false, sizeof(reference));
g_array_append_val(symbols, matchref);
```

And this is what I have tried:

```
typedef struct {
short start;
short length;
char first_mismatch;
} reference;
char *lookahead = NULL;
reference matchref = {0, 0, *lookahead};
reference *symbols;
symbols=(reference *)malloc(sizeof(reference));
strcat(symbols, matchref);
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Start indenting your code.

Comment: First of all, function beginning with `str` are *string* functions. Secondly, you need to learn what the `g_array_append_val` function actually does, and learn about *reallocation*.